# Something that bugs me about RequireJS and dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When writing an application using RequireJS the `reuire`d files are stating their dependencies using the `define( ['actual dependency name'], function (dependency, variables, ...) {})` which is all nice and dandy for using just one or two, but once you start having deeper dependencies it become a little bit complicated and not very readable or maintainable, i.e.:

```
define(['modules/module1', 'modules/module2', 'modules/module3', ...],
    function (module1, module2, module3, ...) {});
```

If I add or remove a dependency I have to rewrite my arguments list in the callback function as well, again - not very maintainable...

Is there a better method of doing this? Am I missing something very simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can be explicit like this:

```
define(function (require) {

    var depA = require('depA'),
        depB = require('depB'),
        depC = require('depC');

    ...
});
```

which should alleviate your maintenance trouble ;)

Comment: This is correct. I suggest creating an anonymous module though, it is more portable:  define(function(require){});

Comment: @jrburke I actually do use anonymous modules in my projects. But could you elaborate on the portability gains? You mean with other libraries, or with extra code to make the module work with non-AMD environments?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was hoping for :)

Comment: ggozad: anonymous modules are more portable to file renaming. A modules name is related to its file name, but once a named define() call is used, it forces the file name to have that module name, unless the developer uses a paths config, which is not ideal.